# UIPageViewController with multiple views

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uipageviewcontroller

I need a dynamic UIPageViewController, the number of pages depends on the quantity of items of my array.

I have two views for this. One for the first page and another one for the other pages. It will be always more than 2 pages (two items on my array).

I'm trying to test with fixed values. But the paging it's not right. The index is not correct.

1st problem, the presentationCountForPageViewController [_vc count] returns nil;

2nd problem, the pagination it's not right. I get to the last page, and the first view it's gone, so if I go back, goes to second view, always...

Please, help!

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        FirstViewController *agenda = (FirstViewController*)[self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
        [_vc addObject:@"FirstViewController"];
        [_vc addObject:@"SecondViewController"];


        self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
        self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;


        NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:agenda];

        [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];


        [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
        [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
        [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

        UIPageControl *pageControlAppearance = [UIPageControl appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIPageViewController class], nil];
        pageControlAppearance.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        pageControlAppearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];


    }




- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

    NSUInteger index = [_vc indexOfObject:viewController];

    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;

    //notice here I call my instantiation method again essentially duplicating work I have already done!
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [_vc indexOfObject:viewController];

    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}


#pragma mark - Page View Controller Data Source

- (UIViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{

    if (index == 0){
        FirstViewController *firstController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController"];

        return firstController;
    }
    else{
        SecondViewController *secondController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
        return secondController;
    }

}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return [_vc count];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you instantiate the `_vc` array?  I suspect it is nil throughout this code.

Comment: Viewdidload. If I change for 2/3, I'm getting the second error.

Comment: I can't see anything in viewDidLoad to initialise _vc, but in any event, you are adding string objects to it (eg. @"FirstViewController") but then you are using indexOfObject to get the index of UIViewController objects (eg. indexOfObject:viewController), so you are probably getting NSNotFound in every case.

Comment: @pbasdf I initiliazed the _vc array. With 4 pages, at 2nd page I'm getting index not found :(

Comment: Have you added extra objects to the _vc array for the additional pages?

Comment: Yeah, look what I did:     for (int i =0; i<[myArray count]; i++) {
        [_vc addObject:(SecondViewController*)[self viewControllerAtIndex:i+1]];
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73030/discussion-between-lucks-and-pbasdf).

Comment: Have you amended your `viewControllerBeforeViewController` (and `...Before...`) to use the _vc array to provide the required view controller?  As it stands, those methods call `viewControllerAtIndex` again, which creates a new view controller, which will consequently not be in the _vc array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments/chat, a few things needed resolving:

1. You need to instantiate the _vc array
2. You need to add `UIViewController`objects to this array, not the strings you currently use
3. You need to amend the `viewControllerBeforeViewController` and `viewControllerAfterViewController` methods to return the relevant element from the _vc array, remembering to test that the index remains within the array's bounds, to prevent swiping beyond the final page, or before the first (agenda) page.